# Using a DataTable of a Sharepoint list, how can I preserve the LookupID

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

When I check the column of the row, it just gives me the value of the lookup, but unfortunately I need the ID.

My workaround is to get the SPListItemCollection, then one by one add the fields I need to a custom datatable, and use that instead. That feels like a hack work around. Is there someone with more experience that knows a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it when you convert SPListItemCollection to datatable with [SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) for a lookup field you do get ID and value in format lie this: "ID;#Value"?

Now, you can use this code to get either ID or value

```
var val = new SPFieldLookupValue("ID;#Value");
val.LookupId;
val.LookupValue;
```

Or is there any other way you convert to datatable?

Comment: I'm using a list.GetItems(query).GetDataTable() to get two datatables, then I'm using a LINQ query to perform an inner join on the two tables to get my final data set. However, I need to take that dataset and perform one more lookup. I suppose I could do it in my LINQ query, but I'm already having issues with making that work right.

Comment: When I do convert it that way, it strips out the ID, and I just get a value.

Comment: Umm, when does it strip out the id? Does GetDataTable() method returns lookups in form like ID;#Value?

Comment: It's weird, when I use GetDataTable() one of my two lookups comes back as value only, the other one comes back as ID;#Value. Of course I'm sure you know which one I need the ID of. I managed to code around it, but the functionality still bugs me.

Comment: Is that fields type is really Lookup field? What if you don't convert to datatable, but what is returned when getting fields value like:  (string)list.GetItems(query)[0]["myFieldName"] ? And what do you get by list.GetItems(query)[0].Fields["myFieldName"].TypeAsString ? (i may have mistake in the code)

Comment: It's really a lookup. If I do spListCollection it preserves the lookupID. Regardless, I recoded it so I don't need a lookupID. I didn't want to do that, but it was taking me too long to figure out the issue. I'll leave this question here because when I get back to it I'll figure out the issue, and post what is going on.